# C++ GNU linker errors

Tags: c++, linker, g++, gnu, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile my program on Windows via Cygwin with the compilation command:

```
g++ ping.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lchartdir50
```

I'm using an API called ChartDirector which draws charts for me. I've never linked libraries this way before (usually I do it through Visual Studio), so I’m a little new to this. I've got a really large list of errors, so I won't list them all, but I’ll list one just to clarify the type of linker errors I’m getting:

> (.text$_ZN9BaseChartD1Ev[BaseChart::~BaseChart()]+0x4f): undefined reference to '_CBaseChart_destroy'

All of these are undefined reference to 'xxx' errors.

I've got a bunch of header files in *./include* and a library called *chartdir50.lib* in *./lib*.

What’s wrong with my compilation line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... that’s odd. I'm using a 64-bit system, but for some reason I tried it with the 32-bit library and it compiled. Thanks!

Comment: Your system may be 64bit, but I doubt the compiler is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but `.lib` have been compiled with Visual C++?

If yes, I don't think it's compatible with GCC. You have to compile the library with GCC/G++ and use that file or to use a compatible binary if you don't have access to the source.

Comment: I tried compiling it in visual studio and I had similar errors.

ping.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CBaseChart_makeChart referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall BaseChart::makeChart(char const *)" (?makeChart@BaseChart@@QAE_NPBD@Z)

Comment: GCC 4.x will link MS object libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I never use that library before, but when I [googled](http://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=en&client=opera&rls=en&hs=TQG&q=lchartdir&btnG=Search&aq=f&oq=) it, I noticed that other people trying like **[-lchartdir](http://www.chartdir.com/forum/download_thread.php?site=chartdir&bn=chartdir_support&thread=1167749540)** instead of **-lchartdir50**, so you should give it a try.

Comment: I tried adding the linux library "libchartdir.so.5.0.0" to ./lib/ and then changing my command line to:

g++ ping.cpp -I./include -L./lib/chartdir

I got the same exact errors.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that library was also created with GCC.

As far as I know, .lib is a static library, so you don't have to point it with the *-l* compiler switch.

Just use it as another file on the command line, like

```
g++ ping.cpp -I./include -L./lib {path to lib here}/chartdir50.lib
```

Comment: Linking the file with -l or specifying the full path are equivalent so that will not affect the situation.

Comment: -l links static libraries or DLL/shared library exports it does not matter.  Also GCC 4.x will link MS object libraries.